# apply_filters from within a Class (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a plugin that makes use of the `wp_mail` function. However I want to change the From: address. WP provides some filters - `wp_mail_from_name` and `wp_mail_from` - but I'm not sure how to call them from within a Class.

If I place them outside of a function there's a parse error (unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION).

If I place them within a function nothing seems to happen

```
class myPlugin {    
    public function setFromname($fromname) {
        apply_filters( 'wp_mail_from_name', $fromname );
        $this->fromname = $fromname;
    }
    public function setFromemail($fromemail) {
        apply_filters( 'wp_mail_from', $fromemail );
        $this->fromemail = $fromemail;
    }
}
```

How is it possible to affect these filters within a Class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WordPress filters must have a call back, they can not use a variable.

```
class myPlugin {
    public function myPlugin {
        add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', array($this, 'filter_mail_from_name'));
        add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', array($this, 'filter_mail_from'));
    }

    function filter_mail_from_name( $from_name ) {
        // the $from_name comes from WordPress, this is the default $from_name
        // you must modify the $from_name from within this function before returning it
        return $from_name;
    }

    function filter_mail_from( $from_email ) {
        // the $from_email comes from WordPress, this is the default $from_name
        // you must modify the $from_email from within this function before returning it
        return $from_email;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `&$this`, instead of `$this`.

Comment: Is that a technicality? In plugins I've written, it works without passing as a reference.

Comment: Sorry about the blunt message :) The WordPress API mentions using &$var everywhere. I just read more about this in the PHP manual. It looks like `&$var` was used for PHP 4 compatibility (to make sure variables are passed by reference in PHP 4). It's not needed in PHP5.

Comment: Thank you. I've read these things on loads of different sites but this just made it click for me.

Comment: Why can't we just use `add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'someemail@somedomain.com');` since the function just returns a string?

Comment: @Popnoodles because add_filter is adding a callback to a list of hooks that expect a function.  The closest thing to what you attempted would be an inline function, something like, `add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', function() { return 'someemail@somedomain.com'; } );`.